# Integrate $\int x^4\sqrt{x^2-3} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

Integrate $\int x^4\sqrt{x^2-3} \, dx$

I tried substituting $\sqrt{x^2-3}=t$ than by squaring both sides and by simplifying i got $x\,dx=t\,dt$ and $x^2=t^2+3$

Now after substituting to integral i have  $\int (t^2+3)^2\cdot t\frac{t\,dt}{x}$, can't get rid of $x$ :(

Don't know how to move on, need a bit help if possible.

Thanks you in advance :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams $x=t^2+3$, no?

Comment: @CameronWilliams sorry for late response,I'm here $\frac{1}{2}\int (t+3)^2\cdot\frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t+3}}dx$, tried integral calc from this step but evaluation is so complicated

Comment: Actually @John that hint was bad on my part. I was doing mental math and thought things worked out better than they do. You'll want to do a trig sub of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

As @CameronWilliams suggested,

$$ x^2 -3 =t $$
and then
$$ x = \sqrt{t+3} $$

(I think you tried to find this in order to get the relation between dt and dx)

Answer (score 2):

Apply the reduction formula

$$\int x^n\sqrt{x^2-3}\ dx=I_n=\frac{x^{n-1}}{n+2}(x^2-3)^{3/2}+\frac{3(n-1)}{n+2}I_{n-2}
$$
to reduce the integral to $I_0$

\begin{align}
\int x^4\sqrt{x^2-3}\ dx=
\left(\frac16 x^3 +\frac38 x \right)(x^2-3)^{3/2}+\frac98I_0
\end{align}
where $I_0= \int \sqrt{x^2-3}\ dx=\frac x2\sqrt{x^2-3}-\frac32\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-3}}x
$.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: for the case $x>0$, the *hyperbolic substitution*
$$x=\sqrt 3\cosh t,\qquad \mathrm dx=\sqrt 3\sinh t\,\mathrm dt$$
and similar for the case $x<0$.
With some hyperbolic trigonometry, you'll obtain a monomial in $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$ for the integrand, which you'll have to linearise.

Comment: With the condition $ x>0$, you mean $x\ge \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Yes. It is mainly because at the end of the substitution, you obtain a $|\sinh t|$ factor.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the integrand function is
$$(-\infty,-\sqrt{3}]\cup [\sqrt{3},+\infty)=I\cup J$$

to get the antiderivative at $ I $, put

$$x=\sqrt{3}\cosh(t).$$

and, at $ J $, make the substitution
$$x=-\sqrt{3}\cosh(t)$$

Comment: similar to @Bernard 's answer............

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore He did not precise the intervals where we compute the antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$ x = \sqrt3 \sec\theta$$ and the integral reduces to :

$$I = \lambda\int\sec^5\theta \tan^2\theta\mathrm d\theta$$

($\lambda$ is a numerical constant) which can be solved with integration by parts. (which is lengthy).

Answer (score 0):

More generally, consider $\int x^4 \sqrt{x^2 - a^2} \,dx$, $a > 0$.

Consider (for $x \geq \sqrt a$) the hyperbolic substitution $x = a \cosh t$, $t \geq 0$, which transforms the integral to
$$a^6 \int \cosh^4 t \sinh^2 t \,dt = a^6\left(\frac{1}{6} \sinh t \cosh^5 t - \frac{1}{24} \sinh t \cosh^3 t - \frac{1}{16} \sinh t \cosh t - \frac{1}{16} t\right) + C .$$
Back-substituting and using that $\sinh t = \sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$ gives
$$\frac{(8 x^4 - 2 a^2 x^2 + 3 a^4)\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}{48} - \frac{a^6}{16} \operatorname{arcosh} \frac{x}{a} + C .$$
Since the original integrand is even, we can extend our antiderivative uniquely to $(-\infty, -a)$ by requiring that it be odd:
$$\operatorname{sign}(x) \left(\frac{(8 x^4 - 2 a^2 x^2 + 3 a^4)\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}}{48} - \frac{a^6}{16} \operatorname{arcosh} \frac{|x|}{a} + C\right) .$$